# Using beautifulsoup and selenium to scrape multipage website returns list of empty strings

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup, slice

I want to iteratively scrape text from a website. Each page of that webpage has the same html structure.
I use selenium to navigate to the next page every time i append the following strings: `text_i_want1`, `text_i_wantA`, `text_i_wantB`, `text_i_wantC`

```
[<div class="col-12">
                            <a href="/url" target="_blank" title="ad i">
                                text_i_want1
                            </a>
                        </div>, 
                  <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div>
                                    date: text_i_wantA
                                </div>
                            </div> 

                            
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div>
                                        source: text_i_wantB
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                             
                
                            <div class="row">
                                <div>
                                    number: text_i_wantC
                                    
                                    <span class="processlink">
                                        <a href="url" title="text_i_dont_want">
                                            text_i_dont_want
                                        </a>
                                    </span>
                                    
                                </div>
                                  
                            </div>

                            
                                
                        </div>,
                 <div class="col-12">
                            <a href="/url" target="_blank" title="ad i">
                                text_i_want2
                            </a>
                        </div>, 
                 <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div>
                                    date: text_i_wantAA
                                </div>
                            </div> 

                            
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div>
                                        source: text_i_wantBB
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                             
                
                            <div class="row">
                                <div>
                                    number: text_i_wantCC
                                    
                                    <span class="processlink">
                                        <a href="/url" title="text_i_dont_want">
                                            text_i_dont_want
                                        </a>
                                    </span>
                                    
                                </div>
                                  
                            </div>

                            
                                
                        </div>,
                  <div class="col-12">
                            <a href="/url" target="_blank" title="ad i">
                                text_i_want3
                            </a>
                        </div>, 
                  <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div>
                                    date: text_i_wantAAA
                                </div>
                            </div> 

                            
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div>
                                        source: text_i_wantBBB
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                             
                
                            <div class="row">
                                <div>
                                    number: text_i_wantCCC
                                    
                                    <span class="processlink">
                                        <a href="/url" title="text_i_dont_want">
                                            text_i_dont_want
                                        </a>
                                    </span>
                                    
                                </div>
                                  
                            </div>

                            
                                
                        </div>, 
                 <div class="col-12">
                            .  
                            . 
                            . 
                            . 
                        </div>]
```

Because `text_i_want1` is not in the same `div` as `text_i_wantA`, `text_i_wantB`, `text_i_wantC`, i used beautifulsoup to get all `<div class="col-12">`
but sliced `[1::2]` the output in order to iterate only over every second `<div class="col-12">` to get `text_i_wantA`, `text_i_wantB`, `text_i_wantC`.
For readability, below i only included three of the otherwise same structured 20 `<div class="col-12">` per page.

```
title,date,name,number = [],[],[],[]
while True:
    soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'html5lib')
    for div in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'title':'ad i'}):
        titl = div.get_text(strip=True)
        title.append(titl)
    else:
        break
    for col in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'col-12'})[1::2]:
        row = []
        for entry in col.select('div.row div'):
            target = entry.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)
            row.append(target[0].strip())
        name.append(row[0])
        date.append(row[1])
        number.append(row[2])  

    next_btn = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".page-next button")
    if next_btn:
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(next_btn[0]).click().perform()
        time.sleep(4)
    else:
        break
driver.close()
```

**Expected output:**

```
title = ["text_i_want1", "text_i_want2", ...]

date = ["text_i_wantA", "text_i_wantAA", ...]

name = ["text_i_wantB", "text_i_wantBB", ...]

number = ["text_i_wantC", "text_i_wantCC", ...]
```

**Problem: Actual output**

```
title = ["text_i_want1", "text_i_want2", ...]

date = ['text_i_wantA', 'text_i_wantAA', ...]

name = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

number = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Why are `name` and `number` empty, in the html there are character values. Is it a problem with css or the loop itself?

.........................................................................................................................................................................................................

**updated question**: integration

```
DRIVER_PATH = 'chromedriver.exe'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
prefs = {"profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
         "download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\aaa",
         "directory_upgrade": True,
         "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH, options=options)
driver.get('https://parldok.thueringen.de/ParlDok/formalkriterien')
driver.maximize_window()
try:
    selenium.webdriver.support.ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'LegislaturperiodenList-button')))
    driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('LegislaturperiodenList').style.display='inline-block';")
    element = selenium.webdriver.support.ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'LegislaturperiodenList')))
    selenium.webdriver.support.ui.Select(element).select_by_value('7')
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)

try:
    selenium.webdriver.support.ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'LegislaturperiodenList-button')))
    driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('DokumententypId').style.display='inline-block';")
    element = selenium.webdriver.support.ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'DokumententypId')))
    selenium.webdriver.support.ui.Select(element).select_by_value('10')
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[class="btn btn-primary"][type="submit"]').click()
```

This is how i setup selenium in order to be able to navigate to the next page. Can you help me putting things together? I dont know how to combine your approach with selenium.

Comment: it would be perfect if you can share the url, as we can figure out some solutions!

Comment: https://parldok.thueringer-landtag.de/ParlDok/formalkriterien
 In `Wahlperiode`, select any and in `Dokumenttyp` select `Kleine Anfrage`. At least on my end, there seems to be a problem with the page atm. I dont know why it keeps loading once the `Wahlperiode` is selected. It did not used to be like that

Comment: Below, you should have an answer for your question, Please, For future questions, DO NOT use the comment section to expand your question. Just [edit] your main question.

Comment: OK, i will not expand my questions in the comment section. Thank you for your answer, it works but is a very different approach. I have difficulties making it work with selenium as i dont only need the first 10 divs on the first page but need to move to next pages subsequently. Any hints appreciated. I edited my question as you can see at the very end of it.

Comment: check updated answer then.

Comment: BTW, in case if that's ingoing project, then use scrapy or any high level async

Comment: thanks so much. its the last part of a project that in retrospect i should have been developing with scrapy from the very beginning, your right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **UPDATED ANSWER**:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from math import ceil


allin = []


def parser(soup):
    goal = (
        (
            x.select('a')[1].get_text(strip=True),
            *list(x.select('.col-12')[1].stripped_strings)[:-1]
        )
        for x in soup.select('.row.tlt_search_result'))
    allin.append(pd.DataFrame(goal))


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        data = {
            "LegislaturPeriodenNummer": "7",
            "UrheberPersonenId": "",
            "UrheberSonstigeId": "",
            "DokumententypId": "10",
            "BeratungsstandId": "",
            "Datum": "",
            "DatumVon": "",
            "DatumBis": ""
        }
        r = req.post(url, data=data)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        print("Extracting Page# 1")
        parser(soup)

        try:
            nextpage = int(soup.select_one(
                '.pd_resultcount').contents[0].split()[-1]) / 10

            for page in range(2, ceil(nextpage) + 1):
                print(f"Extracting Page# {page}")
                r = req.get(f"{url}/{page}")
                soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
                parser(soup)
        except AttributeError:
            print('No More Result Found!')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main('https://parldok.thueringer-landtag.de/ParlDok/formalkriterien')
    final = pd.concat(allin, ignore_index=True)
    print(final)
    final.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

OUTPUT:

```
                                                      0  ...                       3
0     GRW-Fördermittelanträge eines Fertigteil-Herst...  ...  Dokumentnummer: 7/2303
1     Vertretung der Menschen mit Behinderungen in T...  ...  Dokumentnummer: 7/2307
2     Rassistische und rechtsextremistische Aktivitä...  ...  Dokumentnummer: 7/2306
3     Antisemitische Überfälle, Leugnung des Holocau...  ...  Dokumentnummer: 7/2302
4     Finanzierung von Kindertagesstätten in Thüring...  ...  Dokumentnummer: 7/2301
...                                                 ...  ...                     ...
2299               NaturFreunde Thüringen e.V. - Teil I  ...     Dokumentnummer: 7/6
2300  Aktuelle Sicherheitslage für Thüringer Kunst- ...  ...     Dokumentnummer: 7/5
2301  Stand der Planungen zur Ortsumgehung der Stadt...  ...     Dokumentnummer: 7/3
2302  Übergangsbestimmungen zur Neuordnung der Organ...  ...     Dokumentnummer: 7/2
2303  Baustellen entlang der Autobahn 71 zwischen de...  ...     Dokumentnummer: 7/1

[2304 rows x 4 columns]
```

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


def main(url):
    data = {
        "LegislaturPeriodenNummer": "7",
        "UrheberPersonenId": "",
        "UrheberSonstigeId": "",
        "DokumententypId": "10",
        "BeratungsstandId": "",
        "Datum": "",
        "DatumVon": "",
        "DatumBis": ""
    }
    r = requests.post(url, data=data)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    goal = (
        (
            x.select('a')[1].get_text(strip=True),
            *list(x.select('.col-12')[1].stripped_strings)[:-1]
        )
        for x in soup.select('.row.tlt_search_result'))
    df = pd.DataFrame(goal)
    print(df)


main('https://parldok.thueringer-landtag.de/ParlDok/formalkriterien')
```

Output:

```
                                                   0  ...                       3
0  GRW-Fördermittelanträge eines Fertigteil-Herst...  ...  Dokumentnummer: 7/2303
1  Vertretung der Menschen mit Behinderungen in T...  ...  Dokumentnummer: 7/2307
2  Rassistische und rechtsextremistische Aktivitä...  ...  Dokumentnummer: 7/2306
3  Antisemitische Überfälle, Leugnung des Holocau...  ...  Dokumentnummer: 7/2302
4  Finanzierung von Kindertagesstätten in Thüring...  ...  Dokumentnummer: 7/2301
5        Ausstattung der unteren Naturschutzbehörden  ...  Dokumentnummer: 7/2300
6  Antifa-Szene, insbesondere das Arnstädter "Akt...  ...  Dokumentnummer: 7/2291
7  Finanzierung der Beschaffung von Ausrüstung, A...  ...  Dokumentnummer: 7/2309
8                       Statistik der Kfz-Diebstähle  ...  Dokumentnummer: 7/2308
9  Unterstützung des Freistaats Thüringen für Sta...  ...  Dokumentnummer: 7/2299

[10 rows x 4 columns]
```